# Subprocess - get child's exception directly

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I want to get more information about possible exceptions raised in the child. I know it could be done by looking at stderr like below:

```
try:
    completed_process = subprocess.run(['python3', 'test.py'], capture_output=True, check=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.stderr)
```

However, I wonder if I could **directly get the exception raised in the child** such as `ModuleNotFoundError`?

Alternative: some tool for parsing the raw stderr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, because the process tools used in forking / joining aren't aware of any detail except return code and maybe the OS signal that caused the exit.

If you want in-process detail like exceptions you're actually looking for *threading*.

Threading is a way of having parallelism for a subroutine in the same logical processes, and which would allow you to capture in-process details like exceptions.

For python3, details are here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: Thanks! Is it impossible because subprocess module spawns a child by creating another process instead of a thread?

Comment: Correct.  Threads have the context necessary to report the exception.  Subprocesses do not.